# deserialize json newtsoft object

Tags: c#, json

I need to deserialize my JSON, which looks like this:

```
{
   "cart.empty.title":"Il tuo carrello \u00e8 vuoto",
   "returns.confirmation.status.step1.next.arbitration":"A breve riceverai un\u0027email con le istruzioni su come effettuare il reso.",
   "returns.home_pickup.address.form.title":"Dove ritireremo i tuoi prodotti?"
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
drupalRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(apiResponse);

public class Record
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

but I have this error:

```
deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TranslationsTools.Domain.Entities.Record]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Do you know how it should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json string defines a *dictionary*, not a list. If you don't want to define a class, you can simply deserialize the string into a dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsontext = "{ \"cart.empty.title\":\"Il tuo carrello \u00e8 vuoto\", \"returns.confirmation.status.step1.next.arbitration\":\"A breve riceverai un\u0027email con le istruzioni su come effettuare il reso.\", \"returns.home_pickup.address.form.title\":\"Dove ritireremo i tuoi prodotti?\" }";
        var record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsontext);
        foreach (var kvp in record) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdOAho)

You can access elements of the dictionary in the usual way:

```
Console.WriteLine(record["cart.empty.title"]); // prints Il tuo carrello è vuoto
```

However, I strongly recommend defining a class and using it like @[ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) suggests in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67623149/843953)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems:

1. Your `Record` class in no way matches the JSON you've shown. The property names in your object need to match those found in the JSON. In this case that's a bit tricky due to the dots (`.`) in the JSON property names, but luckly Newtonsoft provides a workaround for that - by using its `JsonProperty` attribute to match the C# property to the JSON property, even though the names are different.
2. You need to deserialise to a single object, not a `List`.

You need:

```
public class Record
{
    [JsonProperty("cart.empty.title")]
    public string CartEmptyTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("returns.confirmation.status.step1.next.arbitration")]
    public string ReturnsConfirmationStatusStep1NextArbitration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("returns.home_pickup.address.form.title")]
    public string ReturnsHomePickupAddressFormTitle { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var drupalRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(apiResponse);
```

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LrNc04

(The creation of the `Record` class above was the result of pasting your JSON into https://json2csharp.com/ for automatic conversion.)

Comment: thanks  but i can 1k keys or more on my sample is only 3 but it can more

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. As I showed, you can use an automatic generator to create the class, so you don't have to type it all in.